# How to override style using document.getElementsByClassName with onclick function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to make an image filter like **isotope.js** because I can't and I don't want to use **Isotope.js**.
The Problem is that onclick function is not working with **document.getElementsByClassName();**
All I want to do is that when I click on a link with onclick function that function should set the style of other classes to **display:none;**
Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="CategoriesContainer" class="col l12 m12 s12">
            <div id="Categories" class="col l4 m6 s12 offset-l4 offset-m3">
                <a href="#" class="cat-inner" onclick="showcatall()">All</a>
                <a href="#" class="cat-inner" onclick="showcatweb()">Web</a>
                <a href="#" class="cat-inner" onclick="showcatmobile()">Mobile</a>
                <a href="#" class="cat-inner" onclick="showcatgraphics()">Graphics</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Portfolio" class="col l12 m12 s12">
            <div id="PortfolioItem" class="col l4 web all"><img src="Images/web1.jpg" class="portfolio-img"></div>
            <div id="PortfolioItem" class="col l4 mobile web"><img src="Images/web2.jpeg" class="portfolio-img"></div>
            <div id="PortfolioItem" class="col l4 graphics web"><img src="Images/web3.jpg" class="portfolio-img"></div>
            <div id="PortfolioItem" class="col l4 graphics mobile"><img src="Images/graphics1.jpg" class="portfolio-img"></div>
            <div id="PortfolioItem" class="col l4 graphics"><img src="Images/graphics2.jpg" class="portfolio-img"></div>
            <div id="PortfolioItem" class="col l4 web"><img src="Images/web1.jpg" class="portfolio-img"></div>
            <div id="PortfolioItem" class="col l4 mobile"><img src="Images/graphics2.jpg" class="portfolio-img"></div>
            <div id="PortfolioItem" class="col l4 graphics web"><img src="Images/graphics1.jpg" class="portfolio-img"></div>
            <div id="PortfolioItem" class="col l4 web mobile"><img src="Images/web2.jpeg" class="portfolio-img"></div>
        </div>
```

Can anyone suggest me Javascript for this?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you post your code in jsfiddle

Comment: OP stated he doesn't want to use Isotope.js, what makes everybody think he **wants** to use jQuery?

Comment: Because he did not say anything about not wanting to use jquery

Comment: So because a user did not specify the usage of jQuery, he automatically wants it? It is not needed to import jQuery for merely this task, I don't agree with everyone's need to involve an entire library for this.

Comment: @Roberrrt this is why we told/suggest him that he can use jquery not has to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My proposal is:

```js
// on DOMContentLoaded
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (e) {
  // get all "cat-inner" elements and attach the click handler
  Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementsByClassName('cat-inner')).forEach(function (ele, index) {
    ele.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      
      // get the current text content of the anchor
      var txt = this.textContent.toLowerCase();

      // for each children element set the appropriate visibility
      Array.prototype.slice.call(document.getElementById('Portfolio').children).forEach(function (ele, index) {
        switch (txt) {
          case 'all':
            ele.style.display = 'block';
            break;
          default:
            if (ele.className.indexOf(txt) != -1) {
              ele.style.display = 'block';
            } else {
              ele.style.display = 'none';
            }
            break;
        }
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="CategoriesContainer" class="col l12 m12 s12">
  <div id="Categories" class="col l4 m6 s12 offset-l4 offset-m3">
    <a href="#" class="cat-inner">All</a>
    <a href="#" class="cat-inner">Web</a>
    <a href="#" class="cat-inner">Mobile</a>
    <a href="#" class="cat-inner">Graphics</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="Portfolio" class="col l12 m12 s12">
  <div id="PortfolioItem1" class="col l4 web all">All<img src="Images/web1.jpg" class="portfolio-img"></div>
  <div id="PortfolioItem2" class="col l4 mobile web">Web<img src="Images/web2.jpeg" class="portfolio-img"></div>
  <div id="PortfolioItem3" class="col l4 graphics web">Web<img src="Images/web3.jpg" class="portfolio-img"></div>
  <div id="PortfolioItem4" class="col l4 graphics mobile">Mobile<img src="Images/graphics1.jpg" class="portfolio-img"></div>
  <div id="PortfolioItem5" class="col l4 graphics">Graphics<img src="Images/graphics2.jpg" class="portfolio-img"></div>
  <div id="PortfolioItem6" class="col l4 web">Web<img src="Images/web1.jpg" class="portfolio-img"></div>
  <div id="PortfolioItem7" class="col l4 mobile">Mobile<img src="Images/graphics2.jpg" class="portfolio-img"></div>
  <div id="PortfolioItem8" class="col l4 graphics web">Web<img src="Images/graphics1.jpg" class="portfolio-img"></div>
  <div id="PortfolioItem9" class="col l4 web mobile">Mobile<img src="Images/web2.jpeg" class="portfolio-img"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As i correctly understood, you can create css class with ***"display: none"*** and using

> classList

to manipulate with it. It`s pure JS.

Answer (score 1):

```
function showcatweb() {

  var webs = document.getElementsByClassName('web');
  for (var i = 0; i < webs.length; i++) {
    var imgCnr = webs[i];
    imgCnr.style.display = 'block'; //to hide, imgCnr.style.display = 'none';
  }

}
```

If you dont want to use Jquery

Answer (score 0):

Try with jquery is more simple, when you use vanilla, you need sweep array tith dom elements

1. Call only function
2. Set parameter with class of function
3. Hide all and show only you need

```js
function show(cat){
//hide alll
  $(".web ,.all, .mobile,.graphics").hide()
  
  var categorySearch = "." + cat;
  
  var domElements = document.querySelectorAll(categorySearch);
  //show only category
  $(categorySearch).show()
  
  

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="CategoriesContainer" class="col l12 m12 s12">
            <div id="Categories" class="col l4 m6 s12 offset-l4 offset-m3">
                <a href="#" class="cat-inner" onclick="show('all')">All</a>
                <a href="#" class="cat-inner" onclick="show('web')">Web</a>
                <a href="#" class="cat-inner" onclick="show('mobile')">Mobile</a>
                <a href="#" class="cat-inner" onclick="show('graphics')">Graphics</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="Portfolio" class="col l12 m12 s12">
            <div id="PortfolioItem" class="col l4 web all"><img src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/1" class="portfolio-img"></div>
            <div id="PortfolioItem" class="col l4 mobile web"><img src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/2" class="portfolio-img"></div>
            <div id="PortfolioItem" class="col l4 graphics web"><img src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/3" class="portfolio-img"></div>
            <div id="PortfolioItem" class="col l4 graphics mobile"><img src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/4" class="portfolio-img"></div>
            <div id="PortfolioItem" class="col l4 graphics"><img src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/5" class="portfolio-img"></div>
            <div id="PortfolioItem" class="col l4 web"><img src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/6" class="portfolio-img"></div>
            <div id="PortfolioItem" class="col l4 mobile"><img src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/7" class="portfolio-img"></div>
            <div id="PortfolioItem" class="col l4 graphics web"><img src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/8" class="portfolio-img"></div>
            <div id="PortfolioItem" class="col l4 web mobile"><img src="http://lorempicsum.com/futurama/350/200/9" class="portfolio-img"></div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Thanks.. I have found the solution above... :)

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest that you use jquery and do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.portfolio-img').click(function() {
      $('.portfolio-img').css('display', 'none');
   });
});
```

or use jquery's hide function like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.portfolio-img').click(function() {
      $('.portfolio-img').hide();
   });
});
```

I created a working snippet for you : https://jsfiddle.net/m0o9u8u1/

Comment: Thanks for your effort

Answer (score -1):

Alright, you should be good with a single function for this, so first, in your HTML:

```
<div class="col l4 m6 s12 offset-l4 offset-m3" id="Categories">
    <a class="cat-inner" href="#" onclick="show('all')">All</a>
    <a class="cat-inner" href="#" onclick="show('web')">Web</a>
    <a class="cat-inner" href="#" onclick="show('mobile')">Mobile</a>
    <a class="cat-inner" href="#" onclick="show('graphics')">Graphics</a>
</div>
```

(as graciously provided by Kirmayr Tomaz).

Second, create a function in javascript that responds to this with the parameter you provide:

```
function show(className) {
    // Select and hide all items
    var all = document.querySelectorAll('.list-item');
    for (var i = 0; i < all.length; i++) {
        all[i].style.display = 'none';
    }

    // Display selected items
    var selection = document.querySelectorAll('.' + className);
    for (var j = 0; j < selection.length; j++) {
        selection[j].style.display = 'block';
    }
}
```

[A working codepen example can be found here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YGKJmv)

**General feedback on your code:**

- It appears you're using bootstrap to style your page, the classes you use lack the hyphen that is being used by bootstrap, so a correct way of naming your classes in bootstrap would be:

`col l4 m6 s12` -> `col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12`

- You're using the idea 'PortfolioItem' multiple times. an `id` isn't supposed to be used more than once on a page. You should make a class out of it, and call it `portfolio-item` or something like that.
- Include your javascript in a seperate file, it's good practice to spread `HTML`, `CSS` and `JavaScript in their own file.

Comment: If downvoting an answer that gives normal feedback, including an answer to the exact question is normal, than please explain the reasoning behind it.